# Java 2D - JLabel only partially painted inside JList

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I'm experimenting with 2D painting in Swing, and I'd like to paint a `JLabel` in the middle of an empty `JList`.
Thus I came up with:

```
public class MyJList<T> extends JList<T> {
  private final JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("Whatever");

  @Override
  public void paint(final Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    if (getModel().getSize() == 0 && !emptyLabel.getText().isBlank()) {
      final var preferredSize = emptyLabel.getPreferredSize();
      final var x = (getWidth() - preferredSize.width) / 2;
      final var y = (getHeight() - preferredSize.height) / 2;
      final var g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create(x, y, preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height);

      try {
        emptyLabel.setBounds(0, 0, preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height);
        emptyLabel.paint(g2);
      } finally {
        g2.dispose();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However when the text reaches the bounds of the list, it seems to get truncated:

[image]

If I increase the clipping rectangle width, the label is fully painted.
What am I doing wrong? Is this a good way to paint?

---

Complete minimal example:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final var myFrame = new MyFrame();
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
      super("Example");

      final var list = new MyJList<String>();

      final var contentPane = getContentPane();
      contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      contentPane.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      pack();
      setMinimumSize(new Dimension(160, 200));
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
  }

  public static class MyJList<T> extends JList<T> {
    private final JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("Selezionare un oggetto");

    {
      emptyLabel.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(final Graphics g) {
      super.paint(g);

      if (getModel().getSize() == 0) {
        final var preferredSize = emptyLabel.getPreferredSize();
        final var listBounds = getBounds();
        final var x = (listBounds.width - preferredSize.width) / 2;
        final var y = (listBounds.height - preferredSize.height) / 2;
        final var g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create(x, y, preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height);

        try {
          emptyLabel.setBounds(0, 0, preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height);
          emptyLabel.paint(g2);
        } finally {
          g2.dispose();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to be making an determination on if the label's preferred size will fit within the available space of the label and adjusting it's bounds accordingly.  This will then adjust how the text is wrapped

Comment: Ok I'm a bit lost. What does "label's preferred size will fit within the available space of the label" mean? The preferred size represents the dimension of  the label, so the painting area should use this info. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @Abra the renderer is invoked if there are elements. In this case the list is empty for example.

Comment: @LppEdd *However when the text reaches the bounds of the list, it seems to get truncated:* -  I set the minimum width to 100. As I decrease the width of the frame the label remains centered and the text gets truncated at the beginning and end. Seems reasonable to me. The text is painted to the edge of the frame. I don't see that 10 pixel gap on the left/right that your image shows. I use JDK 11 on Windows 10. What would you expect to happen when the entire text won't fit into the available width?

Comment: It would be quite useful to know which laf you are using. From the image I suspect it's not one of the default lafs.

Comment: @weisj I'm using Flatlaf, but the same happens with the default LaF.

Comment: @camickr I'd expect it to be cut obviously (not to wrap, at least by default), but here in my case the last letter is partially cut in any case.

Comment: Sounds like a Java version or platform issue. The label displays fine for me when space is available for the entire label to be painted. Maybe an option is to use use the Graphics.drawString(...) to paint the text. That way you can use the FontMetrics of the Grraphics object to get the String size. This should take into account the metrics weisj mentioned.

Comment: @camickr I'm on OpenJDK 16, Windows. It's really strange.

Comment: @camickr couldn't it be a Flatlaf issue? The UI part is responsible for setting the sizes.

Comment: You already stated it also happens with the default LAF and your [mre] uses the default LAF.

Comment: Use JavaFX :D I'm amazed that people are still using swing

Comment: @camickr you're right. I'll try with different JDK versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text layout is tricky at the best of times, and the more you can avoid it, the better (IMHO).

Personally, I avoid the custom paint route, but this is me, and try something a little more simpler.

With the use of a `PropertyChangeListener`, to monitor when the `ListModel` changes, and a custom `ListDataListener`, to monitor when the `ListModel` itself changes, you can create a similar result.

One addition here is the fact that I've wrapped the text in `<html>` tags, this will trigger the "word" wrapping.

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton add = new JButton("Add");
            JButton remove = new JButton("Remove");

            panel.add(add);
            panel.add(remove);

            MyList<String> myList = new MyList<>();
            myList.setModel(model);

            add(new JScrollPane(myList));
            add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    model.addElement("Hello");
                }
            });
            remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    if (model.size() > 0) {
                        model.remove(0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class MyList<T> extends JList<T> {

        final private ModelHandler modelHandler = new ModelHandler();

        final private JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("<html>Selezionare un oggetto</html>");

        public MyList() {
            emptyLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(emptyLabel);
            emptyLabel.setVisible(false);
            addPropertyChangeListener("model", new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if ((evt.getOldValue() instanceof ListModel)) {
                        ListModel model = (ListModel) evt.getOldValue();
                        model.removeListDataListener(modelHandler);
                    }
                    if ((evt.getNewValue() instanceof ListModel)) {
                        ListModel model = (ListModel) evt.getNewValue();
                        model.addListDataListener(modelHandler);
                    }
                    updateEmptyLabel();
                }
            });
        }

        protected void updateEmptyLabel() {
            emptyLabel.setVisible(getModel().getSize() == 0);
        }

        protected class ModelHandler implements ListDataListener {

            @Override
            public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent evt) {
                updateEmptyLabel();
            }

            @Override
            public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent evt) {
                updateEmptyLabel();
            }

            @Override
            public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent evt) {
                updateEmptyLabel();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The BorderLayout trick is neat! Are you sure it won't mess up the cell's placement in any way?

Comment: You can see by the animation, I add and remove cells - and since the cell renderer isn't "added" to the `JList` (they are "rubber stamped" through the painting process) it shouldn't have any effect

Answer (score 1):

Calculating text size is difficult and has lots of gotchas. There is a reason why `JList`, `JTable` etc. make use of a renderer pane and not call `paint` on the cell renderer directly.

It is only when a component is part of a frame hierarchy it can correctly determine the size of text. That is because only then the component uses the correct `GraphicsEnvironment` for the current display device. The `GraphicsEnvironment` contains information that is necessary for laying out text as antialiasing support, kerning, fractional font support etc.

So the correct way do what you are doing is to add the label to the `JList` :

```java
public static class MyJList<T> extends JList<T> {
    private final JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("Selezionare un oggetto");

    {
      add(emptyLabel); // <---- add label
      emptyLabel.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(final Graphics g) {
      super.paint(g);

      if (getModel().getSize() == 0) {
        final var preferredSize = emptyLabel.getPreferredSize();
        final var listBounds = getBounds();
        final var x = (listBounds.width - preferredSize.width) / 2;
        final var y = (listBounds.height - preferredSize.height) / 2;
        final var g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create(x, y, preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height);

        try {
          emptyLabel.setBounds(0, 0, preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height);
          emptyLabel.paint(g2);
        } finally {
          g2.dispose();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: If I add the label, it is displayed twice however. It will get painted by paintChildren too

Comment: If you're going to "add" the label to the `JList`, there shouldn't be a need to paint it manually, instead, you need to make a decision about when to show it based on changes to the model instead

Comment: You could also just set the label to not be visible. I’ll update the answer accordingly when I’m back at my PC.